# Is there such a thing as "too many yield statements" in python?

Tags: python, yield

If doing a directory listing and reading the files within, at what point does the performance of yield start to deteriorate, compared to returning a list of all the files in the directory?

Here I'm assuming one has enough RAM to return the (potentially huge) list.

PS I'm having problems inlining code in a comment, so I'll put some examples in here.

```
def list_dirs_list():
    # list version
    return glob.glob(/some/path/*)

def list_dirs_iter():
    # iterator version
    return glob.iglob(/some/path/*)
```

Behind the scenes both calls to glob use os.listdir so it would seem they are equivalent performance-wise. But [this Python doc](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html?highlight=glob.glob#glob.glob) seems to imply glob.iglob is faster.

Comment: Do you have code to share that might illustrate your concern?

Comment: @saidimu: I'm looking at that page but I can't see where it says `iglob()` is faster. It says `iglob()` returns its results *"without actually storing them all simultaneously"* but that doesn't necessarly imply anything about performance.

Comment: I would assume not having to store them all simultaneously has positive speed (and memory) implications?

Comment: @saidimu: Why would you assume that?  You should measure, since it's so easy to use `timeit`: http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html

Comment: @saidimu: "I'm having problems inlining code in a comment".  Never post code in a comment on a question you own.  It's your question.  Update your question.  Don't mess with comments on a question you already own and can fix.

Comment: @S.Lott Storing them all in one go may hit one's system limits if one has a huge number of files to store, whereas "streaming" them one by one won't hit those same limits. Hence my assumption.  

In this particular case I'm not interested in the specific runtime since I'm far from hitting my system limits, but I'm attempting to account for a situation where another user would hit their limits. That's why `timeit` isn't useful in this case.

Comment: @saidimu: I don't get the question (which is on performance) and the comment (which is on overall size and system limits).  I'm lost as to what you're trying to optimize.  Please update the question to clarify if it's storage or speed.  You can't have both.

Comment: Thanks @S.Lott.  

@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams already answered my question (on whether directory listing in python can ever benefit from using yield).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you're doing the directory listing. Most mechanisms in Python pull the entire directory listing into a list; if doing it that way then even a single yield is a waste. If using `opendir(3)` then it's probably a random number, according to XKCD's definition of "random".

Comment: Thanks.

I was debating between os.listdir and os.walk, but I suppose that point is now moot (from a performance perspective).

More generally, are there cases where too many yields become an issue (due to, for example, python's implementation assumptions?)

Answer (score 5):

There is no point at which further use of `yield` results in decreased performance.  In fact, as compared to assembling things in a list, `yield` actually improves by comparison the more elements there are.

Answer (score 1):

using yield is functionally similar to writing a functor class, even from an implementation or performance perspective, except that it can probably actually call the generator a little bit quicker than the `__call__` method on a self-made class, because that is built in to the generator's C implementation.

To hammer this home, the use and rough implementation of the following is the same:

```
def generator_counter():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield i

class functor_counter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0
    def __call__(self):
        i += 1
        return i
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7, the definition of `glob` is

`def glob(pathname): return list(iglob(pathname))`

So at least for this version, `glob` can never be faster than `iglob`.